# javac -cp unable to find or load main

Tags: java, compilation, runtime-error, package

Whenever I compile the java package through this code

```
 javac -cp ch03.stacks StackDriver.java ArrayStack.java BoundedStackInterface.java StackInterface.java StackUnderflowException.java StackOverflowException.java
```

It compiles correctly but when I use this command on the driver class

```
java StackDriver
```

It responds with this error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class StackDriver
```

Why can't I run the main class in the Driver?  And what should I do in order to run the main class?

Comment: Make sure to use semicolon(;) if you are using classpath

Comment: try giving the full path of your obecjt "StackDriver" after java. May be the compile is going to a different directory

Comment: Please provide from what directory you issue the java command. I recommend you to search a little bit prior to asking a question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that in order to run my Driver I must use this command outside the folder

```
java ch03/stacks/StackDriver
```

Which is a bit stupid but I won't dwell on it.

Also discovered a very useful way to compile all of the packages in a folder

```
javac ch03/stacks/*.java
```

I will most definitely remember this screw up and learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

JVM cannot find your main() method. You are probably missing this line of code:

```
public static void main(String args[])  {
//code here
 }
```

Comment: No the StackDriver contains only the main method.